# why this user defined conversion sequence is not prohibited?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

According to c++ standard,

[over.best.ics]

> 4 However, if the target is
>
> (4.1) — the first parameter of a constructor or
>
> (4.2) — the implicit object parameter of a user-defined conversion function
>
> and the constructor or user-defined conversion function is a candidate by
>
> (4.3) — 13.3.1.3, when the argument is the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization, or
>
> (4.4) — 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5, or 13.3.1.6 (in all cases),
>
> user-defined conversion sequences are not considered. [ Note: These rules prevent more than one user-defined
> conversion from being applied during overload resolution, thereby avoiding infinite recursion. — end note ]

```
struct Y { Y(int); };
struct A{operator Y();};
Y y1 = A(); //[[ 1 ]]but this compiles, why this use-defined conversion sequence is considered?
```

in line [[ 1 ]], it's obvious that a "A->A->Y->Y" user defined conversion
sequence is used here. A->A  is identity conversion A->Y is conversion function, Y->Y is identity conversion.

Comment: Why do you think it *is* prohibited by the paragraph you quote?

Comment: The standard says that user-defined conversion sequences are not considered, but line [[1]] actually uses user-defined conversion.

Comment: OK, why do you believe that this case falls within the scenarios in which this paragraph is applicable? Which bullets do you think apply, and why?

Comment: In line [[1]], the compile will call copy constructor Y(const Y&) to initialize y1, but A() is of type A, so it will be converted to type Y. According to 13.3.1.4 [over.match.copy] Copy-initialization of class by user-defined conversion, it is apparently a copy-initialization of Y by user-defined conversion(A::operator Y()).  So bullet 4.4 apply here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you saw the first example (and modified it):

```
struct Y { Y(int); };
struct A { operator int(); };
Y y1 = A(); // error: A::operator int() is not a candidate
```

The crux is that invoking the converting constructor for `int -> Y` constitutes a user-defined conversion, but `Y -> Y` [`const&`] does not. [over.best.ics]/6:

> When the parameter has a class type and the argument expression has the same type, the implicit conversion sequence is an identity conversion.

I.e. in your code, there is one sole user-defined conversion sequence, not two; It consists of two standard conversion sequences (being identity conversions) and the intermediate user-defined conversion `A -> Y`. You could also have returned a subclass:

```
struct X{}; struct Y : X {};
struct A { operator Y(); };
X y = A();
```

…now the second standard conversion sequence has Conversion Rank - [over.best.ics]/6 again:

> When the parameter has a class type and the argument expression has a
>   derived class type, the implicit conversion sequence is a
>   derived-to-base Conversion from the derived class to the base class. […] A derived-to-base Conversion has Conversion rank (13.3.3.1.1).

Comment: in your code, there is one sole user-defined conversion, not two;

Comment: "in your code, there is one sole user-defined conversion, not two"
do you mean that because there is only one user-defined conversion sequence, so there is no need to do overload resolution.

Comment: @JackChin That was a typo indeed, I meant user-defined conversion sequence.  And no, overload resolution is performed.

Comment: The standard says that user-defined conversion sequences are not considered. But in my example, the one and only one user-defined consequence is taked into consideration. Does this contradicts?

Comment: @JackChin No, it doesn't. This paragraph talks about converting the *result of the user-defined conversion* to the parameter of the ctor.